# Twilio Error 11200, Bad Gateway 502 - Intermittent Issue

Tags: twilio

I am having an intermittent issue with Twilio. Once out of every 50 or 75 calls, we get a call that fails, and when I check the logs, it states that it is error 11200, and it gives a Bad Gateway 502 message "An upstream server received an invalid response".

I've taken a look at Twilio's suggestions regarding this error (found at https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/11200). They list a bunch of probable causes for a bad gateway error:

1) Web server returned a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response to Twilio  - as far as I can see in the logs, the web server is returning a 200 HTTP response to Twilio. 
2) Misconfigured Web Server - We have checked the configuration of our web server, and believe it to be correct. 
3) Network disruptions between Twilio and your web server - we have tested the ping response time, and the packet loss between www.twilio.com and our server. The ping time is < 100ms, and there seems to be no packet loss when testing with ping -n 100 www.twilio.com
4) No Content-Type header attached to response - we set our Content-Type to application/xml. 
5) Content-Type doesn't match actual content - We set our Content-Type to application/xml and are using the TwiML language to send our responses back.

We have also checked all elements in Twilio's Possible Solutions section for this error.

A bit about what we are doing:

API Version: 2008-08-01

We only make outgoing calls.

We use TwiML to send a Say command, followed by a Gather. It is during the Gather that we get our intermittent error. The user will press a key, which gets sent back to us. Depending on which key is pressed, we then send another Say to Twilio - for example "You pressed 1. This offer has been accepted. Thank you." or "You pressed 2. This offer has been declined. Thank you."

I'm not ruling out that it's something at our end that is causing the issue, but we don't really know what to check next. The web server appears to be sending a 200 response back, but Twilio seems to be receiving a 502.

Does anybody have any suggestions that might help us out? Could it be a problem with the API we are using? Should we be upgrading to 2010-04-01?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not sure what's going on here, so I recommend you get in contact with Twilio support at help@twilio.com. If you can share with the support team some call SIDs where this happened, they will be able to investigate further.

Comment: We've started seeing the same thing in the past few days for incoming text messages from twilio. About 2/3 of them error out with a 502 on Twilio's side, and we do not see any incoming requests in our logs. The other 1/3 work perfectly.

Comment: @Keith, any chance you came across a solution/reason for this? We're experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell - Unfortunately no, I haven't been able to determine the cause of the issue as of yet.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but with random `404` response for my webhook configured for inbound messages that forwards request to my api